# c# comparing a value in a text box to a field value in Access Database table

Tags: c#

I need to read a value in a text box and compare that value to a field in an Access database Table field, if the value in the text box does not exist then provide a message as shown in the code, if it does exist carry on with the rest of the code. Here is what I have, it returns the message if the value is or isn't present in the database table field?? I do not know what I have done incorrectly.

```
{
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand comd = new OleDbCommand();
            comd.Connection = connection;
            comd.CommandText = "IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Players WHERE DOB= '%" + txt_DOB.Text + "%')";
            MessageBox.Show("You must register before you can add activities!");

            //Function to reset all text boxes in Activity Section
        ClearBox2();

        }
```

Comment: Start by reading over how ado.net works and then try this again. I do not mean that as an insult. It's just that once you grasp the fundamentals then executing trivial tasks like checking for a record etc. become easier to execute. [Google - c# ado.net tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+ado.net+tutorial&*)

Comment: Thank you Igor I will, only been coding 4 weeks and on a deadline to finish an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("yourConnectionString"))
{
    OleDbDataAdapter adap;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    OleDbCommand comd = new OleDbCommand();
    comd.Connection = connection;
    comd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", "%" + txt_DOB.Text + "%");
    comd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Players WHERE DOB LIKE @param";

    adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(comd);
    adap.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows == null || dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        MessageBox.Show("You must register before you can add activities!");

}
```

Comment: Hi daniell89 thanks getting an exception when using this, I have not been coding very long only 4 weeks, trying to finish an assignment for University.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

Comment: I resolved the connection issue, however the code is allowing the same issue I have previously, in as much as if the dob is present it will show the message it is not then register details and if not present it will display message and save details, any suggestions?

Comment: What was the problem? I can edit and improve my answer.

Comment: Hi Daniel your code worked, I needed to change the setting in the access form from number to short text as the number when entered in a text box beginning with 0 in access the 0 was deleted so no match, thank you for your help.